# HttpRequest not found in php

Tags: php, httprequest

I just want to make a httprequest with post parameters. I used this code

```
$r = new HttpRequest($url, HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$r->send();
```

but I get this error:

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'HttpRequest' not

I added `extension=php_http.dll` this to my php.ini, but the problem still exists.
I download the php_http.dll file and inserted it in the ext folder of php but it was already existing so I replaced and still have the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: hi, have you verified that the dll exists in the extension folder of php?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using php 5.4 or above, there does not seem to be a php_http.dll file to include in your extensions library (Unless someone can find one that I missed??).

The only one that I could find generated errors on starting up the Apache server after updating the php.ini configuration file to include the extension.

Fear not however, as there seems to be a GitHub Project which provides the functionality within a class, rather than an extension. [Click here to find the required class](https://gist.github.com/twslankard/989974).

If you save this class in your project and call like so;

```
include_once('HttpRequest.php'); //where HttpRequest.php is the saved file
$url= 'http://www.google.com/';
$r = new HttpRequest($url, "POST");
var_dump($r->send());
```

Failing that, it would seem that the only other viable option would be to compile the .dll yourself from the source [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http)  :(

Otherwise, another option would be to use cURL instead. cURL provides most (if not all) of the functionality of the `httpRequest`.

A simple example of this would be;

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/";        
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body 
$head = curl_exec($ch); 
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch); 
var_dump($head);
```

More details and better examples can be found on the php website [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php/)

I hope this helps answer your question, rather than leave you with more...

Comment: `php_http.dll` for PHP 5.4 can be found at https://github.com/stealth35/stealth35.github.com/downloads

Comment: Ah, was I being blind after all? Thanks for the assist with locating the php_http.dll. Do you know if the mentioned .dll runs correctly after including in `php.ini` and restarting the Apache Service?

Comment: Works fine with my PHP 5.4.7 installation. `phpinfo()` reports that the extension `http` version `1.7.4` is enabled and working.

Comment: Must be my build, or the version I downloaded then. I'll get the one from stealth35 and update

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure you have a `php_http.dll` that matches your PHP version. You can do `<?php phpinfo();` to check with extensions are loaded (look for "http", it will list the version and available classes).

If the extension does not appear in `phpinfo()`, you should check your logs to learn where the problem comes from or run the PHP binary directly from the command prompt — `php -i`. If there is any error loading a dynamic library it will show up in a dialog box. Note that PHP will still continue to function even though an extension failed to load.

Answer (score 4):

you can reinstall the package

```
$ pecl install -f pecl_http-1.7.6
```

or access the data using curl  like [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31318117/1166727)