# httprequest to curl in php 5.5.38 on Windows

Tags: php

I'm hoping someone can help me out.  I inherited some code that I have no idea how it works and now that it broke I have to fix it.

I am running PHP 5.5.38 on Windows server 2012 and IIS 8.5.  I have finally discovered that the php code is using httprequest which doesn't exist anymore in my version of php and with windows.  How would I convert the following to use curl code, if it is even possible?

```
$http = new HttpRequest('https://my.securelink.com/external/readi/ssoRequest', HttpRequest::METH_POST);

$http->addHeaders(
    array(
        'READI_AccessKey' => $accesskey, 
        'READI_Timestamp' => $timestamp,
        'READI_RequestSignature' => $mac
    )
);

$http->addPostFields(
    array(
        'READIUsername' => 'myusername',
        'LastName' => $_GET["lastn"],
        'FirstName' => $_GET["firstn"],
        'Email' => $_GET["em"],
        'ForceNewAssessment' => false,
        'InternalID' => $_GET["userid"],
        'IncludeSettings' => ''
    )
);
//Optional Post Field:  'READIUserID' => 'xxxxxx'


$response = $http->send()->getBody();

echo "<h3>===== Response ===== </h3>";
echo "<pre>";
echo $response;
echo "</pre>";

$arr = xml2array($response);

$rtn_status = getvaluebypath($arr,'sso/status');
$rtn_timestamp = getvaluebypath($arr,'sso/timestamp');

if($rtn_status == "success") {

    $redirectURL = getvaluebypath($arr,'sso/redirectUrl');

    echo "<h3>===== Access Link ===== </h3>";
    echo "<a href=\"" . $redirectURL . "\" target=\"_blank\">" . $redirectURL . "</a>";
    header( "Location: $redirectURL");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpRequest not found in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579407/httprequest-not-found-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the `HttpRequest` class as [guyver4mk suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20621965/3209381) ([the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579407/httprequest-not-found-in-php) from *Jiri Hrazdil's* comment) if you don't want to change the whole code.

But since you asked how to convert the existing to cURL, try this:

```
$header = [
    'READI_AccessKey: '.$accesskey,
    'READI_Timestamp: '.$timestamp,
    'READI_RequestSignature: '.$mac
];


$post = [
    'READIUsername' => 'myusername',
    'LastName' => $_GET["lastn"],
    'FirstName' => $_GET["firstn"],
    'Email' => $_GET["em"],
    'ForceNewAssessment' => false,
    'InternalID' => $_GET["userid"],
    'IncludeSettings' => ''
];

$ch = curl_init();

$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://my.securelink.com/external/readi/ssoRequest',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
];

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$response)
    print_r(curl_error($ch));

curl_close($ch);
```