# CartoDB - SQL API - Post request with php

Tags: php, http, cartodb

In my app I'd like to send some small amount of data to my cartodb-table with my php-script.
I would like to use the [SQL-API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api.html#write-data-to-your-cartodb-account). My app parse the data in the form like:

```
https://{account}.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=INSERT INTO test_table (column_name, column_name_2, the_geom) VALUES ('this is a string', 11, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-110, 43),4326))&api_key={Your API key}
```

I tried several functions `http_get, file_get_contents, http_request` but nothing pass the data to my account. Put when I copy/paste the URL and open in the browser, everything is added.

What's the right function? There so many different ones... [PHP-HTTP-Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.http.php)

**EDIT**

With the code from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873187/make-a-https-request-through-php-and-get-response) I get this error, when I print out the response:

```
{"error":["syntax error at end of input"]}
```

within the browser I get this:

```
{"rows":[],"time":0.038,"fields":{},"total_rows":1}
```

my request code right now:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullurl);
// Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Get the response and close the channel.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print($response);
```

Comment: Could be a certificate issue as it is requested on https,  look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873187/make-a-https-request-through-php-and-get-response)

Comment: Works that I get e response. But I get the error {"error":["You must indicate a sql query"]}

Comment: Could you edit the questiom to include the error message ?

Comment: Edit my post with code and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the result: with `CURLOPT_POST => 1` it works!

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => "https://".$cartodb_key.".cartodb.com/api/v2/sql",
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Sample cURL Request',
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    api_key => $api_key,
    q => "INSERT INTO spot (".implode (", ", array_keys($data)).") VALUES (".implode (", ", $data).")"
  )
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Great that you found a solution by yourself