# sending token in url

Tags: php, api, curl

```
`curl -H "Authorization: Token token=YOUR_TOKEN" https://api.upcall.com
 /api/v1/calls`
```

how to used in php means how to request in php

```
$service_url = "https://api.upcall.com/api/v1/calls";
$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: 12345' // you can replace this with your $auth variable
));
```

Comment: What's a question about ? Oh.. now I see...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a header using a HTTP request through a curl call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call)

Comment: get data curl -H "Authorization: Token token=YOUR_TOKEN" https://api.upcall.com
 /api/v1/calls  in how to get data in php?

Comment: Did you try to read this article [php curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php)? Also 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873187/make-a-https-request-through-php-and-get-response

Comment: https://upcall.github.io/api-docs/?shell#calls

Answer (score 0):

Your api call should be something like so:

```
$service_url = "https://api.upcall.com/api/v1/calls";
$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Token token=YOUR_TOKEN'
    ));
$result = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );
```

Above is the php conversion of the curl command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token token=YOUR_TOKEN" https://api.upcall.com/api/v1/calls
```

Comment: return value  false means null

Answer (score 0):

```
    $url = 'https://api.upcall.com/api/v1/calls';
    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: token=YOUR_TOKEN'
    );
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );
    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );
```

Comment: get method not post method