# Get api result from URL using PHP

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

The following URL is from the FobBugz API documentation:
https://kakapo.fogbugz.com/api.asp?cmd=search&q=project:inbox%20assignedTo:Elinor&cols=ixProject,ixPersonAssignedTo,sTitle&max=2&token=04t9123822q4kbba09nt740inhibk2   ([you can find it here](http://help.fogcreek.com/the-fogbugz-api/cases#Search_Cases_cmdsearch))

If I copy and paste the above URL into a web browser I get an XML response. What I would like to do is create a function that returns the XML response as a its result.

I am so stuck, it is simply not working.  All I seem to get in response is an empty string.  When I use this 'example' on the FogBugz site I get XML telling me that I am NOT logged in.

The function below comes mostly from here: [Make a HTTPS request through PHP and get response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873187) I have been messing with it for hours without success.

```
function searchBug(){

$data =  "https://kakapo.fogbugz.com/api.asp?cmd=search&q=project:inbox%20assignedTo:Elinor&cols=ixProject,ixPersonAssignedTo,sTitle&max=2&token=04t9123822q4kbba09nt740inhibk2"; 
    //echo $data;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, False);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

[EDIT: in response to comment]
The response that I want to receive is:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<response>
<error code="3">
<![CDATA[ Not logged in ]]>
</error>
</response>
```

As that is what is shown in my browser when I paste the URL and press enter.

Comment: And what  do you want to receive?

Comment: Well, the error is allready show, you are simply just not logged in, you probaly need to make a `login` `call` first.

Comment: i tried it, it works for me

Comment: @mrweinh - in response to your deleted answer, I have an account and API token but since I get a result from the example I figured that a PHP script should return the same.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misunderstood your question. You weren't wondering why the response was that you are not logged in, you were wondering why the PHP script did not receive any response, right?

Comment: @mrwienh Yes... using my own token and being logged in I still get nothing.  But when I paste the exact same URL into the browser I get the expected result.  Oddly I can do this with in visual basic using MSXML2.XMLHTTP object.... but that is not helping me either :-/

Comment: Have you tried to check what curl_error() returns?

Comment: @mcklayin - are you saying that you have an XML response using PHP?

Comment: @mrwienh - I'll google how to do that, but if you can provide the line(s) of code to achieve that I'd appreciate... very new to PHP

Comment: You can catch errors during the call like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php

Comment: @SlowLearner yes, if you want to see you xml response in browser, don't forget to send xml headers

Comment: Added the error handler from above (and changed to $ch) but still get the same

Comment: @mcklayin I think the problem was XML headers... its working now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php
function searchBug($path){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retValue;
}

$sXML = searchBug('https://kakapo.fogbugz.com/api.asp?cmd=search&q=project:inbox%20assignedTo:Elinor&cols=ixProject,ixPersonAssignedTo,sTitle&max=2&token=04t9123822q4kbba09nt740inhibk2');
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $sXML;
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/f5fj44

Comment: Ok - based on this I got a little further, enough to delete HTML header from the document....  thanks

Comment: @SlowLearner  glad to help you :):):)